# Setting position and look direction of a GameObject (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a bendable game object comprised of a number of bones. The bones positions are calculated using some joints and some maths and that is all working as expected. But I am struggling to rotate the bones to face the correct direction. I'm settings the bones positions like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= bonesCount; i++ ){
    Vector3 newPosition = someFunction();
    bones[i].transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

And that works correctly:

[image: 1]

But when the bendable object bends the bones retain their original rotation:

[image]

I thought I could use `Transform.LookAt` on the bone at position `i` to look at the bone at position `i + 1` but this gives strange results:

[image: 3]

It seems like it's an issue with using the wrong axis (up, right or forward).

Any suggestions? Is `Transform.LookAt` the correct method to be using?

Comment: If it's looking backwards, then simply use transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - target.position);

Comment: Could you provide a picture with the desired result and the current situation? its not quite clear to me what you are struggling with.